# How do I proceed past this location with an eye and a blocked door?

Tags: in-verbis-virtus

I've been stuck  at this location for about 30 minutes now, and I'm at a lost as to how to proceed. On the side opposite the entrance there's a door which is blocked by two pillars.

[image]

Down a hallway to the left there's an eye statue, which has a journal entry just called "The eye".

[image]

[image]

Finally, to the right, there's a symbol which is called "Mark of Command" (the name shows up when interacted with).

[image]

I currently have two spells: **Light** and **Beam of Light**,  neither of which seem to help  me here. I tried shining **Beam of Light** on various things in the room, including the eye, but it doesn't really do anything.

How do I proceed past this room?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out the solution is to actually read all those journal entries you get!

**The Observor** inscription is  the one which holds the solution, and it's located in a room shortly before you come across a circular elevator. It's the room with a narrow walkway, and those blue bird things flying around.

[image]

At the end of this room, just before you'd go out into the larger cavern, you'll stumble across a brightly lit room filled with glowing mushroom jellyfish things.

[image]

Go to the back of this room and you'll find **The Observer** inscription, which contains the information you need.

[image]

[image]

So in order to proceed past this room you need to walk (not run) down the hallway with the eye, with your head facing the floor (aka look down). You'll know you're doing it right because you'll hear music playing. Once you get to the eye, just look up, and a cutscene will start to play (I waited for about 5 or 10 seconds before looking up at the eye, so it's possible waiting a few seconds before looking at the eye is required). After the cutscene plays you'll get a new spell which will open the door when used on the **Mark of Command.**